# objective-c if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

So this is probably really simple but for some reason I can't figure it out.  When I run the below code I can't get it to go into the `if` statement even though when I go into the debugger console in xcode and I execute `po [resultObject valueForKey:@"type"]` it returns `0`.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your help!

```
NSManagedObject *resultObject = [qResult objectAtIndex:i];

if (([resultObject valueForKey:@"type"])== 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of `valueForKey:` is always an object — and the only object equal to 0 is nil. In the case of a numerical value, it will be an NSNumber. At any rate, I think you want to ask for `[[resultObject valueForKey:@"type"] intValue]`.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly!  I knew it was something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the NSManagedObject to an int (if thats what it actually is...)

Also you don't need the extra parentheses around the [ ]

```
NSManagedObject *resultObject = [qResult objectAtIndex:i];

if ((int)[resultObject valueForKey:@"type"] == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This will just check if the object is nil and is essentially equivalent to the original example. If will not check if the object's value is 0.